# Implement email validator with android patterns

Tags: java, android, validation, user-interface

I am trying to implement email validation in my app, using android patterns, but every time nothing is returned when I call my function `isEmailValid(String)`.

can anyone help?

```
        //Valida conteúdo do email
        char_Email.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus){
            if(!hasFocus){
                email = char_Email.getText().toString();
                isEmailValid(email);

            }
        }

        private boolean isEmailValid(String email){
            return Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
        }
    });
```

Comment: isEmailValid is returning a boolean value, but you are not storing/using the boolean value within onFocusChange which is returned by isEmailValid method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
//Valida conteúdo do email
char_Email.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus){
        if(!hasFocus){
            email = char_Email.getText().toString();
            boolean validEmail = isEmailValid(email);
            if(!validEmail) {
                 // Do something, maybe show a Toast
            }
        }
    }
    private boolean isEmailValid(String email){
        return Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }
});
```